# Retrofit 2, how can I access received ArrayList in other activity?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, gson, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit with `Gson` to get some data from my server in my Splash activity.
Now when the call is complete it writes data to `Gson` Model Classes automatically,

Right Now I have made static `ArrayLists` of those model classes and writes data to them from call response but this doesn't sound like a good approach.

I was wondering what is the better approach to solve this problem?

Is there Anyway I can get data from these Model Classes directly in other activities using `Gson`?

or I would have to send them from one activity to other? if so then how can I send them as they already have Serialized annotation.

Thanks

Comment: Send it via EventBus.

Comment: Maybe a good way to do it is using the observer pattern with rxjava: http://randomdotnext.com/retrofit-rxjava/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're more possible solutions how to solve this:

1) Use EventBus (for example [Otto Bus](https://square.github.io/otto/)) and pass it via this. You also can use [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/The-RxJava-Android-Module) and Observable pattern, but this requires more work.

2) Create a DataHolder singleton, store data in it and use it everywhere you need

3) Pass it via an Intent to Activity

I personally do prefer 1 and 2, since passing the data through the intent doesn't provide the luxury of shared data. RxJava (+ MVP) also provides many other benefits, but it's not the topic of your question.

Comment: Hi slanecek thanks for your detailed answer, I see `otto` is deprecated in favor of `RxJava`, while [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) is updated regularly so is it better to use `EventBus`? and how the subscriber in `MainActivity` will get data if `MainActivity` is not created yet when we dispatch events from `SplashActivity`?

Comment: @Anders You may use Sticky Events, http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/11/28/android-how-to-use-the-greenrobot-eventbus/